# My script throws error while clicking on links cyclically

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11

I've written a script in vba in combination with IE to perform clicks on some javascript links connected to each profile of a webpage. My script can click on the first link flawlessly but when it comes to click on the next link in it's second iteration, it throws `permission denied` error. There are on valid links connected to each profile so I can't use the links as navigation. How can I modify my script in order to click on links cyclically?

This is my script:

```
Sub ClickLinks()
    Const Url As String = "https://intraweb.stockton.edu/eyos/page.cfm?siteID=58&pageID=7&action=dirmain&type=FAC&display=basic"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Htmldoc As HTMLDocument, I&

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate Url
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Htmldoc = .document
    End With

    With Htmldoc.querySelectorAll("#main table tr a")
        For I = 0 To .Length - 1
            .Item(I).Click  'in second iteration this line throws permission denied error
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
        Next I
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an XHR request. The following does an initial `GET` request to retrieve all the staff IDs. It then loops the ids issuing `POST` requests for each id. To show it visits each page, I retrieve the staff e-mail address from each page.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim objHTTP As Object, URL As String, html As New HTMLDocument, i As Long, sBody As String
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    URL = "https://intraweb.stockton.edu/eyos/page.cfm?siteID=58&pageID=7&action=details"

    With objHTTP
        .Open "GET", "https://intraweb.stockton.edu/eyos/page.cfm?siteID=58&pageID=7&action=dirmain&type=FAC&display=basic", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        Dim staffIDs As Object
        Set staffIDs = html.querySelectorAll("input[name=employeeID]")

        For i = 0 To staffIDs.Length - 1
            sBody = "employeeID=" & staffIDs(i).getAttribute("value")
            .SetTimeouts 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000
            .Open "POST", URL, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
            .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            On Error Resume Next
            .send (sBody)
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                If .Status = "200" Then
                    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
                Else
                    Debug.Print "HTTP " & .Status & " " & .statusText
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Else
                Debug.Print "Error " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Source & " " & Err.Description
                Exit Sub
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
            Debug.Print html.querySelector("td a").innerText
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Sample view on landing page:**

[image: sample view]

---

**Sample code printout from page:**

[image]

---

Clunky time based wait for refresh and then navigation back to landing page so can submit next form. This needs improvement and some re-ordering.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ClickLinks2()
    Const URL As String = "https://intraweb.stockton.edu/eyos/page.cfm?siteID=58&pageID=7&action=dirmain&type=FAC&display=basic"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Htmldoc As HTMLDocument, i&

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Htmldoc = .document

        Dim numEmployees As Long, a As Object
        numEmployees = Htmldoc.querySelectorAll("a.names").Length

        For i = 1 To 3                           'numEmployees   (1-792)
            While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            .navigate URL
            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
            .document.parentWindow.execScript "document.form" & i & ".submit();" ''javascript:document.form1.submit(); ''<== Adapted this
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Although the number connected to each form incremented like 1,2,3, etc, I don't find any difference whether the loop is `For I = 1 To 2` or `For I = 1 To 5` because It only navigates to the first profile page and stops there. There is no iteration happening.

Comment: It changes for me. I end up on the page of whomever is the last number. The problem is the interim. If I try and pause then it errors out as it has re-directed and no longer has the original form to submit. This will happen with whatever method you try unless you can find a way to collect the re-directs and navigate to them independently in separate browser instances. If you new the staff ids you could also XHR.

Comment: Thanks QHarr for your solution. It seems I need to improve my batting average (giving more details to the question to bring the clarity). I create very hardly any post to scrape the data; rather, I try to learn the pattern following which i may get rid of such problems in future cases. So, If I encounter any such error again (dealing with another site) I'm still unaware how may I deal with that.

Comment: I like your questions. So this is a tough one...the problem here is that you need the landing page to make the next submission via your clicks (I think). So you could navigate back to the landing page and submit the next form...clunky... or simply mimic what clicking actually does which sends POST request to retrieve the info. I have added another solution which works which is where I got to with a non XHR solution of navigating back to landing page.